# Input radio button change algorithm

Tags: php, jquery, html, algorithm, loops

Shop. Cart

```
name  |  price  |  count  |  price*count
apple      2         2           4
banana     3         4           12

Delivery
(radio button) none                       | checked
(radio button) to home (+3)
(radio button) to another town (+6)


Total Count               |      16
```

- When you change count - my script dynamically recounts total count and changes with Jquery Total Count text()

Now I just need to change dynamically Total Count text when delivery changes.

I just dont get **HOW**.

If I change it to `to home`, Total Count += 3, then if I change `count` for item, Total Count += ((price*newcount)-price*count)

**But** when I change delivery to `another town`, Total Count+= (new input - prev.input radio), but when I change back to 0, Total Count-= (input value)

My JQuery script simply on change takes the value of `price*count`, multiplies `price` and `count` siblings values and checks - and if it differs, changes the Total Count text.

```
var updating = false;
if(!updating){
   updatePrice();
}

function updatePrice(){
   var pricewas = pricecountitem.text();
   var pricenow = pricecount;
   var difference = pricenow - pricewas;
   var numadd = 1;

   if(difference < 0){
      pricecountitem.text(+pricewas - numadd);
   }else if(difference > 0) {
      pricecountitem.text(+pricewas + numadd);
   }

   if(difference !== 0){
      updating = true;
      setTimeout(updatePrice, 1000);
   }else{
      updating = false;
   }
}
```

---

I just cant write the algoritm how dynamically to change the value including all cases of delivery and count changes.

My head is going to blow up, can you guys please help me,  ?

Comment: Why are you trying to compute the difference ? can't you just simply recompute the whole price and change it anyway ? does it matters that the price has changed as long as you are displaying the correct value ? You may also store the subtotal (without delivery) and simply recompute the total (subtotal+delivery) on change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

added delivery on next page, where info is inputed. question closed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).